# Swift empty array does not have a member named .insert

Tags: arrays, swift

I am new to Swift.

I am trying to get some data from a webservice and to loop the JSON data to make a simple array.

```
DataManager.getDataFromEndpoint{ (endpointData) -> Void in
    let json = JSON(data: endpointData)

    if let programsOnAir = json["data"]["data"]["on_air"].array{
        var onAirArray = []

        for onAir in programsOnAir {
            var eventName = onAir["event_name"].string
            var eventCover = onAir["event_cover"].string
            var tuple = (name: eventName!, cover: eventCover!)

            onAirArray.insert(tuple, atIndex: 1)
        }

        println(onAirArray)

    }

}
```

I get an error where the member .insert does not exist

BUt if I init the array like this `var onAirArray = [name: "something, cover: "somethingelse"]` then it works.

I need to work with empty arrays and I need to be them mutable, because I have no idea what I may get from the JSON given by the API endpoint.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
var onAirArray = []
```

Since you haven't given the array an explicit type, this is creating a new instance of NSArray, which doesn't have a method called insert. Which is why this is probably the exact error message you're receiving.

> 'NSArray' does not have a member named 'insert'

To fix this, explicitly state the type of your array.

```
var onAirArray: [(String, String)] = []
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem!! But what if can't define the type from the begin, for example what if the tuple is made of String, NSDate?

Comment: @Anonymous Then you would use `var onAirArray: [(String, NSDate)] = []` or if it was a combination of Strings, dates, etc, `var onAirArray: [(String, AnyObject)] = []`. Either way, you'll need to specify the type of the array in some form ahead of time to make sure that you've using a Swift Array and not NSArray since NSArray is incapable of storing tuples.

Comment: Last question I promise :) Do you think is it a good way to store the JSON object in an array made of tuples, where each tuple represents the data of each different object in the array?

Comment: @Anonymous I would say so. It beats lugging around a dictionary or array if you only ever need two objects in it.